# How to data store and get everywhere in site of bigcommerce like React state management and Angularjs manage scope or data service

Tags: bigcommerce

I am very new in Bigcommerce. I want some data store or set like state management of React  and  manage scope or data service of Angularjs and use set data anywhere of Bigcommerce site.

Our any other way to set data and use anywhere of site.

Bigcommerce work same as JS with graphQL.

Comment: Could you clarify what your exact goal is? What kind of data are you trying to store/access, and how are you trying to access it? If you could give an example this would also help

Comment: suppose when product page load and I store product ID and that product ID use or get anywhere big commerce. Like Session.

Because Bigcommerce not provide the access of any PHP files. we can create html files and work with JS. 
I need to way like Angularjs. In Angularjs you can set any value in Scope variable  and and use that variable  anywhere of our site through angularjs.

I think you clear this time. if you need any clarification please let me know.